# Convert array value with comma seperator php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this ...

```
Array
(
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => abc
                    [1] => xyz
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => abc
                    [1] => def
                    [2] => ghi
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => abc
                    [1] => def
                )

        )

)
```

I want a result like this as a comma separator value

```
abc,xyz
abc,def,ghi
abc,def
```

Pls suggest me the solution .. .

Thank you

Comment: function implode()

Answer (score 7):

You will need [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) to achieve this:

```
foreach ($array['options'] as $values) {
    echo implode(',', $values);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: select it as an answer if it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

USe implode() function:

```
foreach($mainArr['options'] as $arr) {
   echo implode(",",$arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "";
foreach ($array as $first)
{
  foreach ($first as $second)
  {
    $string .= implode(',', $values);
    $string .= "<br>";
  }
}
echo $string;
```

If you decide to add more arrays than just `[options]`, the previous code will not break.

Comment: Great , its working but using implode() we can reduce the code.

Comment: @MrudangShah yes I changed it to include implode :), and also if you decide to add more arrays than just `options`, my previous code will not break

Comment: One thing that i wants to know from your code is that what $string .= "{$third},"; is doing exactly. ( in your previous code)

Comment: @MrudangShah It's a technique used to add extra elements to a string. Instead of doing for instance `$string = $string."<br>"`, you can do `$string .= "<br>"` and you will get the same result. Oh and if my answer worked for you, please give it a upvote (and or green checkmark) to let future readers know it helped :)

Comment: yes sir its working ... i am just thinking that how simple it is and i worked on it for a whole day !!! :D

Comment: @MrudangShah I am happy that it has :). Oh and if you didn't know, on the top left of my answer, you can see two arrows, 1 is an up arrow, and the other is a down arrow. Below the down arrow there is a grey checkmark. If you click that checkmark, it means the answer has worked for you. Try clicking it

Comment: @MrudangShah No you haven't :). Try looking under the grey arrow pointing "down" in my answer. You should see a grey "check mark". When you click it, it turns green. You probably are new to stackoverflow and haven't used the feature yet which happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Use implode to join array elements with string

```
foreach ($array['options'] as $a) {
echo implode(',' , $a,);
echo '</br>';
```

}